# Val_loss in Keras using TFRecord

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I was building a model in Keras using Tensorflow's Dataset function and TFRecord. I succeeded in the training model with Keras, but the problem lies in val_loss. It is not showing at all in Keras's progress bar.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
      x_train,y_train = input_fn('train_whale_without07.tfrecords')
      x_test,y_test = input_fn('test_whale_without07.tfrecords')

      img_input = layers.Input(tensor = x_train)

       model = CNN(img_input)

       model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                   metrics=[categorical_crossentropy, categorical_accuracy], 
                             target_tensors=[y_train])

       model.fit(steps_per_epoch=3000, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=None, verbose=1, validation_data = ([x_test,y_test]))
       model.save('my_model_keras.h5')
```

The results are like this

> Epoch 1/15
>      1/3000 [..............................] - ETA: 00:05:12 - loss: 8.1786 - categorical_crossentropy: 8.1786 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Anybpdy know how to add val_loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation loss and metrics are only computed at the end of an epoch, not during training. So it won't be shown while iterating batches on the training set, only at the end of the epoch.